# Enable all controls on form when using multithreading?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I don't know my way right or wrong when i want to start some jobs, i will disable all control and enable again when jobs completed. This is my code :

```
public void EnableControls(bool isenable){
this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{   
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        control.Enabled = isenable;
    }
}));}
```

with : this is form control

Everybody can explain me that this code is wrong or right. When i use many threads, i see controls cannot enable and i don't know why. Thanks !

Comment: did you try to set this.Enabled = isEnabled instead? it should enable/disable all childs

Comment: @ArsenMkrt Sorry, i'm forgot i need to keep "stop button" to stop jobs if users want.

Comment: could you put all controls that should be enabled/disabled in the panel, and enable/disable panel instead?

Comment: no have panel or group-box... here. Only button, datagridview and some label. I don't have any problem when i want enabled it. Here problem is that when all jobs completed, sometime controls did not enable again :)

Comment: @HùngLêXuân: If you disable ALL controls, the form becomes useless for the user? So whats the reason to keep the UI thread "alive" when the user cant do anything in it anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `enable/disable` all controls in the form, you can just use `form.Enabled` instead. If however there are some controls that you don't want to take a part in enable/disable you can put all controls that are interested in `Panel` or `GroupBox` and `Enable/Disable` panel. And at least if you can't use `Panel`, your code is fine in this case